# Javascript/jQuery object and data bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding

Is there some javascript or jQuery binding solution (similar to knockout js) that allows you to bind a property of an object (e.g. height/width/x/y, etc.)? With knockoutjs you have to create your own binding variables in the viewModel object, and then bind other things to those variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben Nadel has written about [binding events To non-DOM objects With jQuery](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1520-Binding-Events-To-Non-DOM-Objects-With-jQuery.htm), although I'm pretty sure it isn't formally supported.

Comment: So he's just essentially using a timer to check for changes to the watched 'thing', which won't really work in my case. Very good read, though, thanks.